# Laravel Scout - observe relations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

When I import the index everything works fine (including relations).

The problem is that the main model does not watch over relations.

When I update a relation, the index is not updated too.

Is there any way to use something similar with `Cache::tags` to update the index when a relation is modified? Or maybe is another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, unfortunately, no direct way to do this using Scout. However, using another Laravel feature you can 'trick' Laravel into updating the record.

Add a `$touches` variable to each of the child classes containing the method names of the relationship to the parent. For example, if you had a Comment class with a `post()` method returning the `belongsTo()` relationship, you'd add to the Comment class:

```
protected $touches = ['post'];
```

When a comment is modified, it will update the `updated_at` field of the parent, which Scout will see and update the record.

Comment: This might not work for `*Many` relationships, e.g. `belongsToMany`. There was an attempt to fix this for 5.1, but this still seems to be an issue as of 5.6: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19275